# How to pass params in angular api call

Tags: angular

I have a function which is used to cancel a job. It looks as shown below:

```
 cancelJobById(jobId) {
        return this.httpClient.post(this.urlService.baseRestEndpoint + '/tracecollection/cancelJob?cmd=cancel&' + jobId, {});
    }
```

This function is working as expected. Now I have to rewrite this function to build query params using the below function:

```
generateParamFromObject(object: { [key: string]: string }): HttpParams {
        let params = new HttpParams();
        Object.entries(object).forEach(([key, value]) => {
          if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            value.forEach((val) => {
              params = params.append(key, val);
            })
          } else {
            params = params.append(key, value);
          }
        });
        return params;
    }
```

I have tried to rewrite it as below, but it isn't working after the change:

```
cancelJobById(params) {
  params = this.generateParamFromObject(params);
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.urlService.baseRestEndpoint}/tracecollection/cancelJob`, { params });
}
```

Comment: params as an object? Being that it's already the object you want: You might not need the {} on the params. Also, what does your API object look like? A List<T>, a Dictionary? Do you have a swagger to verify your object is the right shape?

Answer (score 0):

In your http call i can see you are passing the httpParams in the body parameter.

you should do

```
cancelJobById(params) {
  params = this.generateParamFromObject(params);
  const body = {} // body request
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.urlService.baseRestEndpoint}/tracecollection/cancelJob`, body, { params });
}
```

You can see the post documentation

```
  post<T>(url: string, body: any | null, options?: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    observe?: 'body';
    params?: HttpParams | {
        [param: string]: string | string[];
    };
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: 'json';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
  }): Observable<T>;
```

Answer (score 0):

for single values you probably should use .set

```
params = params.set(key, value);
```

but in reality, you dont have to build httpParams yourself, angular will build it for you from your object

```
params = params// no modification
this.httpClient.post(`${this.urlService.baseRestEndpoint}/tracecollection/cancelJob`,null, { params });
```